# How do I empty the back stack?

Tags: android, dialog, back-stack

I am using `DialogFragment`. I have three dialogs that appear one after another.

Countries List --> States List --> Regions List

I have tow button on each of these dialogs, `Cancel` and `OK`. I put current dialog onto stack before I show next dialog. Now a user may press `Cancel` button on say, States List dialog. I don't want him to be taken back Countries List dialog. I just was to exit the dialog. Similarly, I don't want stacked dialogs popup when a user presses `OK` button. I want to end the dialog gracefully and update the database.

I searched on SO and google docs. I found this should be achieved with this:

```
FragmentManager ft = getFragmentManager();
ft.popBackStack("mydialog", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

But it doesn't work for me. I tried to place it inside `builder.setNegativeButton` and also inside `builder.setPositiveButton`. Nothing seems to work.

Here is how I put them on the stack:

```
    RegionsDialogFragment dialogFragment = new RegionsDialogFragment ();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mydialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    dialogFragment.show(ft, "mydialog");
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

It seems I wasn't clear. I am able to put dialogs unto the stack. That is not a problem. Problem is how can I empty(not popup) back stack when I no longer need to show stacked dialogs? I don't want stacked dialogs to popup on their own again. I want them to die on the stack and don't come back. I want to empty the stack. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need add to back stack the dialogs, if you want close a Dialog, you should use: `dimiss()` method.

Note:
You are setting null in `addToBackStack()` method

Comment: I add them so that a user can go back to previous dialog. I want to empty the stack if user presses `Cancel` button on second or third dialog. `dismiss()` will not work in this case.

Comment: Your Note was the answer. I had to put same same string as in the below code instead of `null`

`FragmentManager ft = getFragmentManager();
ft.popBackStack("mydialog", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`


Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: Please see the EDIT in the post.